# Regex: match letters WITH numbers only

Tags: regex

How can I create a regex expression that will match only letters **with** numbers?

I've tried something like `(?>[A-z]+)([a-z0-9]+)`.

The regex should give the following result:

```
1234b --> true
1234 --> false
abcd --> false
abcd4 --> true
12b34 --> true
```

Comment: Quite curious why this question is downvoted...

Comment: What should happen with *1a2* or *a1b*?

Comment: Is `é` a letter in your scenario? Did you know `[A-z]` also matches characters like `|`? Which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*`

Basically, where 1 and a are any number and any letter, it matches 1a or a1, surrounded by any number of alphanumeric characters.

edit: shorter and probably faster now

Comment: exactly what I was searhing for 3 hours, and I put example too https://regex101.com/r/vU9aU9/1

Answer (score 6):

Other answers are incorrect, and will allow any string that only contains letters, numbers or both. My expression will specifically exclude strings that consist only of letters or only of numbers.

```
[A-Za-z0-9]*([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)
```

Any number of letters and numbers, followed by at least one letter followed by a number or at least one number followed by a letter.

There is possibly a simpler way of doing this, however. Mine seems long winded. Maybe it's not. Anyone care to pitch in? :P

Comment: Thanks Thats it!  actually easy

Comment: Pitching in: `^(?:[0-9]*[A-Z]|[A-Z]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]*$`. Use the case-insensitive modifier of whatever regex engine you're using.

Comment: @TimPietzcker actually not working: `echo 'a1b2' | grep -o -E "(?:[0-9]*[A-Z]|[A-Z]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]*$"`

Comment: @TimPietzcker oh, my fault, I'll fix it. But we suppose this guy want to get 'a1b2' matched?

Comment: @billybob: Oops, you were right, I did make a blunder: It should be `^(?:[0-9]+[A-Z]|[A-Z]+[0-9])[A-Z0-9]*$`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`^([a-Z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-Z]+)[a-Z0-9]*$`

and a simpler version inspired by TimPietzcker:

`^([a-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-Z])[a-Z0-9]*$`

Comment: Almost correct!  It's good to see an ERE solution (since this is a simple problem and shouldn't require PCRE).  But depending on your parser, `[a-Z]` may not mean the same thing as `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: @dazzafact He updated his solution when I'm writing this answer :)

Comment: When the range of possible best solutions is small, it's pretty much certain there'll be overlap :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it be one regex if you don't have to.  Use two regexes that both have to match.  In Perl, it would be like this

```
if ( /[a-zA-Z]/ && /\d/ )
```