# PHP preg_match exclude

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

OK this regex will match string like 2aa, a2, 2aaaaaa, aaaa2, aaa2aaaa, 2222a2222-2222-aaaa... in short, mix of alphanumeric characters in a sequence:

```
preg_match("/(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*/i")
```

now I want to exclude something but I'm stuck, something like this doesn't work

```
preg_match("/(?!1920x1200|1920x1080)(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*/i")
```

for example the string `aaaaa222aaa1920x1200bbbbb1234556789` is still matched but it shouldn't because it contains `1920x1200`

any help is appreciated :)

i'm using regex found here for matching alphanum sequences [Regex: match only letters WITH numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951756/regex-only-match-letters-with-numbers/13952055)

regex test: https://regex101.com/r/vU9aU9/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your negative lookahead should have `.*` in front to allow for 0 or more characters before not-allowed text. Also use anchors in your regex.

regex should be:

```
preg_match('/^.*?1920x1200.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*/im')
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE0mF2/12)

Comment: but 2222a2222-2222-aaaa string should also be matched because of first sequence  2222a2222 is combination of alphanum. chars

Comment: please take a look at updated demo https://regex101.com/r/wE0mF2/4 this is almost what i want, only the last string is not matched and it should be, if i add $ to the end then last 3 strings won't match, this regex is confusing for me :)

Comment: my original code works exactly what i wanted, -_,. are not important, it can be any other non-alphanum character... now i just want to not match whole string if it finds 1920x1200 somewhere, a2 alone will match, a2-aa will also match, aa-22 will not match, aa22-1920x1200 will not match because of 1920x1200, sorry my english isn't perfect :(

Comment: my first code works great, take a look, i just want to not match anything on that line if it finds 1920x1200 https://regex101.com/r/wE0mF2/6

Comment: I think you're missing something important here. Without anchors whole block of string is considered one single string. To avoid matching a line with `1920x1200` you have to tell lookahead to disallow match till end of line hence anchors have to be used.

Comment: yes something like that, avoid matching a line with 1920x1200 because 1920x1200 is exactly alphanum sequence what i'm matching in the first place, but i don't want that sequence to be matched and make whole line false

Comment: YESS finally you understand me :) this is exactly what i asked for

Comment: oh well after some more test and little modification, this is not what i wanted unfortunatelly https://regex101.com/r/wE0mF2/8 first group should match in all lines, second should't. maybe because of my broken english i cannot explain better, but what can i do, maybe it's not possible in regex after all

Comment: yes, you are right, i'm pretty amateur at regex and i don't know all terminology :( i think i'll stick with this solution, it almost works as expected (except that 2 lines in group two) https://regex101.com/r/wE0mF2/11

Comment: In that case I hope you will mark this answer as selected :) I will see meanwhile if any other solution can be found.

Comment: amazing, NOW this is exactly what i wanted, it works in every possible combination, thank you very much @anubhava, you're really regex master :)